# how to apply transition effect in expand/collapse inside gridview rows

Tags: javascript, css, gridview

Below Javascript function is used to expand/collapse the gridview rows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divname);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "inline";
            img.src = "Img1/minus.gif";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            img.src = "Img1/plus.gif";
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my gridview I m calling the javascript like below and its working fine but its expanding immediately. I want to expand the panel slowly. How can I apply the css transition effect in it. I dont know where to apply the css. can anyone help me.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="JavaScript:setTimeout(divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>'),1000);">
                <img id='imgdiv<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>' width="9px" border="0" src="Img1/plus.gif"
                    alt="" /></a>                        
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="20px" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expansion, you can add the CSS `transition` property like so:

`#element_id { transition: all 1s ease }`

The `all` refers to the properties that will be affected by the transition. If you only want the transition to affect width, replace that part with `width`.

However, your example involves updating the element's `display` property to `none`, which can cause silly things to happen e.g. setting `display: none` via JavaScript will cause the element to be immediately removed from view. You'll have to try something like using a `setTimeout` the same length as your width transition:

```
function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divname);
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
    if (div.style.display == "none") {
        div.style.display = "inline-block"; // allows width to be altered
        div.style.width = "100px"; // or whatever desired width is
        img.src = "Img1/minus.gif";
    } else {
        div.style.width = "0px"; // initializes transition;
        setTimeout(function(){
            div.style.display = "none"; // will happen after transition..
        }, 1000); // ..bc we set the transition time to 1s in css
        img.src = "Img1/plus.gif";
    }
}
```